# Who is the top-hatted person in the new Doctor Who trailer?

Tags: doctor-who, character-identification, actor-identification

Who is this person in the Doctor Who trailer released on 23rd October 2022?

My family are convinced it's Matt Smith/Eleventh Doctor, and it looks like him to me too.

But as I can't find anything about it on the internet I assume it probably isn't. (Assuming that if it is Matt Smith it'd be all over the internet by now.)

So, is this Matt Smith/11th, and if not do we know who it is - either actor or character?[image]

Comment: My brain's facial recognition system says it ain't Matt Smith.

Comment: https://www.doctorwho.tv/news-and-features/neil-patrick-harris-joins-doctor-who

Comment: I don’t think this falls foul under the future works policy; this is simply asking for the identity of the actor, not the character the actor will portray.

Comment: A lot of face blindness going around it seems.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It seems that Neil Patrick Harris will be appearing as an unspecified character:

[image: Photo of Neil Patrick Harris in white tie dress with a white carnation and a black top hat, his eyes shadowed.]

https://twitter.com/bbcdoctorwho/status/1537115775739240450

> Doctor Who: The Power of the Doctor 
> @bbcdoctorwho
> A very happy birthday to Neil Patrick Harris, filming new #DoctorWho today!

Harris has suggested that he will be [playing a villain](https://www.instagram.com/p/CewO_VbsiTn/):

> nph [Verified] My current gig. Never looked more dashing. Thank you for inviting me into your Whoniverse, @russelltdavies63 . I’ll try my hardest to do my worst. This Doctor has no idea what’s in store. And even if he does… Who cares? Ha ha ha HA ha-ha-ha! @bbcdoctorwho

And apparently Davies has confirmed that Harris will be playing "[the greatest enemy the Doctor has ever faced](https://www.instagram.com/p/CewMhpPtRkg/):"

> russelltdavies63 [Verified] Neil Patrick Harris, welcome to Cardiff! Playing the greatest enemy the Doctor has ever faced. Such a great actor, such a great man, it’s an honour and a hoot. Have fun! @nph @bbcdoctorwho ♥️Ha!

Comment: Neil Patrick Harris playing a a doctor? [How novel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doogie_Howser,_M.D.)

Comment: It is NPH, but the character is believed by many to be the Celestial Toymaker.

Comment: @AdrianWragg - cool, do you have a source for this? Would make a good answer, or a good addition to this answer.

Comment: @WiggotheWookie At the moment it is just speculation unfortunately (e.g. https://www.radiotimes.com/tv/sci-fi/doctor-who-neil-patrick-harris-accent-newsupdate/). It's been going around for a while, but the nature of the most recent regeneration (no spoilers deliberately) has indicated that the Doctor may be about to face an enemy who can alter reality itself - which the Toymaker certainly can.

Comment: "The greatest enemy the Doctor ever Faced" : so he is playing the Doctor then....

Comment: I know white male is no longer a requirement to play The Doctor, but he/she still has to be British, right?

Comment: Could it be "The Master"?

Comment: @Machavity you mean Dr. Horrible, right? ;)

Comment: @tilley31 - Only until some showrunner decides otherwise. They will probably be played by British actors in the near future, but since the Doctor is a regenerating alien, they could literally be anyone. And since the Doctor is not even a "normal" Time Lord (the whole Timeless Child business), even the basic human-like body plan of the Time Lords cannot be a guarantee.  The showrunners break old trends all the time: I certainly was not expecting the latest twist regarding whom the Jodie Whittaker Doctor regenerated into.